# Como colocar fundo responsivo no col-md

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, layout-responsivo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para esse fundo não se repetir? 
html:

```
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default sharp">
            <div class="conteudo_me">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.col-md-12 -->
```

css:

```
.conteudo_me {
background: url(../img/view.png);
height:255px;
width:100% auto;

background-position: 0px 280px; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Isso deve atender...

```
        background: url(../img/view.png) no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;
 display: compact;
```

Isso deve funcionar.

Comment: Quando eu coloco o backgroun-repeat, a imagem some.

Comment: Usei o seu plano de fundo aqui e funcionou certinho... Me chama no skype, posso te ajudar melhor.

gu_bat